# Does “sheeple” refer more to an individual or to a group of people as a collective noun?

Tags: meaning

The word "sheeple” is explained in *The New Oxford American Dictionary* as:

> people compared to sheep in being docile, foolish, or easily led

It's an informal and derogatory word. An example sentence is given:

> By the time the sheeple wake up and try to change things, it will be too late

According to the above defination and example, Is "sheeple" used to refer to an individual person, or a certain population as a collective noun?

Comment: It's a portmanteau of sheep and people and, like *people*, is used as a plural.   If it were used as a singular noun the example in the dictionary would have been:  "By the time the sheeple **wakes** up and **tries** to change things..."

Comment: Is it acceptable to say "He is such a sheeple"?

Comment: In this kind of informal conversation it's pretty much acceptable to say anything as long as the person you're speaking to understands what you mean.  In this case I think it would be immediately understood.

Comment: You're free to simply call one person a sheep. That metaphor is well established without this word. FWIW, I don't think "sheeple" is all that derogatory. These days, it's basically shorthand for "I'm a conspiracy theorist" and I hear it used most often to make fun of the speaker, not anyone else.

Comment: Would the singular of "sheeple" be "sheeperson"? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was talking about a single person, I wouldn't use "sheeple." It's meant to be a portmanteau of *people*, which is plural. When referring to an individual, I'd stick with a wording like, "He is so gullible."